# Provision to compare js files from cache and application using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, browser-cache

I have few js files in my application.When ever I change anything in these files,I have to clear my browsers cache to see my changes.In order to avoid this I have used this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js?cacheBust=20"></script>
```

But this doesn't seem to work.
I do not want to use versioning in the URL like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js?v=1.2.3"></script>
```

The problem with this is , if I forget to change the version,the browser still uses the old js file.
I just want to know if there is any easy method ,where the current browser's cache js file is compared with the application's js file.If there is any change then load the new file , else use the old file.

I'm working on ASP.net application with jquery and bootstrap.There is no server side code in my application. So I would appreciate if some one could suggest any solution on client side.Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: you need to set the headers of the file to tell the browser not to cache the file. Otherwise versioning is probably the only other way.

Comment: You can try disabling caching, not sure about other browsers but google chrome developer tools has this under Network tab

Comment: I do not want to disable caching as I will loose the advantages of caching

Answer (score 0):

## Disable cache for developing

### Client Side

**In Chrome** Open the developer tools (f12) on the 'networ'k tab check 'disable cache' from the toolbar. Notice this will only be a valid state as long as the developers tools are open. Now reload the page and notice the page loading without cache.

[image]
**In Firefox**, open developer tools, click the settings cog, goto 'advanced settings' and check 'Disable HTTP Cache'. (same notice as chrome I presume)

### Server Side

Depending on which server setup, you can set headers with all sorts of options, like expiry dates and things to tell the browser when they get a new version.

[**node.js**](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/simple-server-side-cache-for-express-js-with-node-js-45ff296ca0f0)
In the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_headers) it states there are header options for: *if-modified-since*, *if-unmodified-since*, *last-modified*

[**nginx**](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/) - [proxy_cache_revalidate](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html?&_ga=2.52068329.1155923114.1513892886-254232906.1492204201#proxy_cache_revalidate) instructs NGINX to use conditional GET requests when refreshing content from the origin servers. If a client requests an item that is cached but expired as defined by the cache control headers, NGINX includes the *If-Modified-Since* field in the header of the GET request it sends to the origin server. This saves on bandwidth, because the server sends the full item only if it has been modified since the time recorded in the *Last-Modified* header attached to the file when NGINX originally cached it.

[**appache**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/caching.html) If the response has a status of 200 (OK), the response must also include at least one of the "Etag", "*Last-Modified*" or the "*Expires*" headers, or the max-age or s-maxage directive of the "Cache-Control:" header, unless the CacheIgnoreNoLastMod directive has been used to require otherwise.

Comment: I do not want to disable cache. I want it to update the new js file only when there are some changes in it.. Is there any way to compare the cache file and the actual js file.?

Comment: I've edited my answer, take a look. You'd check that server side and set the header for that, take a look at the "modified" options.